# How to change file names using regular expressions in Python?

Tags: python, regex, file

I have a directory which contains subdirectories which contain files. All the file names have a prefix which I want to eliminate. The prefix is not exactly the same among all the files, but I have a regular expression that represents exactly the language of these prefixes. I'm trying to write a script in Python to change the name of each file to its name without the prefix. I don't know yet how to "play" with files in Python (know just basic i/o operations). Could you help a little?

I use Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find these functions useful:

- [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir)
- [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)
- [`os.rename`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename)

You might want to look at using [`glob.glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.glob) if the prefixes you are trying to match are supported by the language glob uses (it doesn't support full regular expressions, but it does allow some wildcards).